# Is there any option to make it work? global+local varriable

Tags: javascript

I'm new to JavaScript and I have a problem with using global and local variables. I want function "check" to return [1, 2, 3]. Thanks in advance :)

```js
const players = [1, 2, 3, 4];

check();    
function check()    
{     
    players.pop();    
    console.log(players);    
}
```

Comment: `return players`?

Comment: You only have one variable declared in your question. Where is the `global and local variables` aspect?

Comment: As per @CertainPerformance do you want the function to actually return. As it does do what you need. Agreed it is not best practice to influence variables in this way.

Comment: Sorry, there are too many incongruities in your question to answer it accurately. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of w shallow copy and this will work in this scenario

```js
const players = [1, 2, 3, 4];

check();    
function check()    
{   
    // CAUTION : This is only a shallow copy and will work with value types
    // If you use on ref types, it will be pointing to the same objects.
    let innerArr = players.slice();
    innerArr.pop();    
    console.log(players); 
    console.log(innerArr);
    return innerArr;    
}
```